# Can I say "Being walking down the street, I met my old friend."?

Tags: grammaticality

I know *walking down the street, I met my old friend* is much better.

I just wonder if the sentence is grammatically incorrect, or it's acceptable like in the case of passive participles as below.

> e.g. Being surprised at the news, I couldn't say a word.

vs.

> Surprised at the news, I couldn't say a word.

Comment: "Being surprised at the news" could be acceptable; "Walking down the street" is such a widely used idiom that "Being walking down the street" sounds wrong.

Comment: *Surprised* can be used transitively, *walked* cannot, except when there's a police officer involved. Or, I suppose, anyone with a handgun.

Answer (score 2):

The doubled-up progressive "being walking" is not used. I believe what you meant was:

- **While** walking down the street, I met my old friend.

However, "Being surprised by. . ." (be + predicate modifier) is fine.  And so is "Surprised by. . . ".  Choose whichever you think sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

"Having walked down the street, I met my old friend" I think, would be better and more correct if you wanted it to be passive participle.

Comment: Hello, potatoesandnoodles, and welcome to English Language & Usage. If possible, please cite a reference authority for your conclusion above. In general, we try to encourage answers backed by a reasoned explanation and cited reference works, rather than answers that amount to uncorroborated opinions. Thanks!